# Permissions issue, 403 on CiviCRM install

Tags: installation

I've installed CiviCRM for WordPress without issues in the past but I've encountered a problem on one particular host. CiviCRM installs OK but when I launch the Installer I get a 403 on https://my.site/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm&reset=1. I've tried changing permissions on the CiviCRM plugin folder but no luck.

Any ideas on where the issue may lie? I'm running v. 5.53.0

Comment: Have you asked your host about it? That's a permission error, so it's more likely to be a hosting issue. Usually when I've encountered it, either the permissions or user/group are wrong. The host can typically look at the logs and get better information.

Comment: Thanks Jenni, yes, it's clearly a hosting issue and the company's support people have no ideas at this point. As you suggest, I'll ask them to review their logs.

Comment: I usually try to recreate the issue while I'm working with them so it's right there in the logs. All errors like that should show something in the logs. If they can't do something that simple, then my next recommendation would be a new host. That's pretty much basic stuff for a host to help out with.